# how connect to sql server developer from a client system?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have written a Windows forms application in vb.Net (Visual Studio 2010) and my form is completely connected to a SQL Server 2008 database. All things are true when using my program in my machine but when I try to run it by other systems in the network the following error occur:

> A network -related or instance -specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL
>   server. the server was not found or was not accessible......

I have installed framework.net3.5 and Microsoft SQL Native Client

But do not any special settings .
i have installed developer version in my pc!!
Please help me I need some basic helps because its my first time to do some things like this.
thanks

**Connection string** is:

```
<add name="Mosalasbandi.My.MySettings.Contorol_FaniConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=Ehsan-PC;Initial Catalog=&quot;Contorol Fani&quot;;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps in this blog post may help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx